# Spring Boot1.5.3でaccess.logをファイルではなく標準出力に出力するには

Tags: spring-boot

環境Google Cloud Platform(GKE)
Spring BootアプリケーションをGKEを使ってデプロイしています。
tomcatのaccess.logファイルをファイルには保存できたのですが、
クーバネイティスが標準出力を拾ってStackDriverに転送してくれるため
ファイルではなく、標準出力に出力したいのですが、可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

トリッキーな方法ですが、[こういうやり方](https://github.com/ImmobilienScout24/tomcat-stdout-accesslog/issues/2)があるみたいです。

なので、Linuxであれば`application.properties`に以下の定義を追加すれば、うまくいくのではないかと思います。

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=/proc/self/fd
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=1
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=false
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b
```

---

※Tomcat 8.0のアクセスログの出力は`org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve`が担当していて、`conf/server.xml`の`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" …`
の箇所で細かい設定をしています。

これと同様のことは、Spring Boot 1.5.3では`application.properties`(または`application.yml`)に`server.tomcat.accesslog.`で始まる定義をすることで実現できるはずです。

どちらの設定もコンソールに出力するようなオプションは無いので、カスタムの`AccessLogValve`をつくらないと実現できないのかもしれません(前述のようなトリッキーや方法を使わないのであれば)。